# Phone number format in Peoplesoft 9.1

Tags: format, phone-number, peoplesoft

I'm trying to find where the phone number format is specified and stored in Peoplesoft 9.1. When ever I enter a phone number(like XXXXXXXX) in the personal data page, after saving it, the phone number is getting stored in a particular format (like XXX-XX-XXX). I verified all the peoplecodes but couldn't find from where this format is being loaded.

Need your help.

Answer (score 2):

To set up number formats, use the Number Format (`RBT_NUM_FORMAT_CMP`) component.

For more information, see

- PeopleSoft Number Management 9.1 PeopleBook (May 2012)

  - Chapter 3: Administering Phone Numbers

    - [PDF version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35947_01/psft/acrobat/crm91cpna-b0512.pdf)
    - [HTML version](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35909_01/crm91pbr1/eng/psbooks/cpna/book.htm?File=cpna/htm/cpna01.htm)